# Which is better way to implement report module in a .Net2005 client-server application? Crystal Reports or SSRS

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I am building a client-server application in .Net2005 with sql server 2005.
I want to generate reports on my Client software which is intracted to server with a web service. These are large amount reports. SO i want to know which way is better:
1. Crystal reports
3. Simple text report.
3.HTML Report

Thanks
Asif

Answer (score 2):

Anything that's not crystal reports would seem to be a good idea.  As a point of interest, when you upgrade to .net framework 4/VS2010, you'll find that CR is no longer included - you can download it separately though.

I've used SSRS before and found it to generally be pretty good.

---

Drawbacks (as per request).  Note that this is my personal opinion/experience, others may differ.

1. Designer is hard to use and not tremendously intuitive when you move beyond the simple.
2. Many different versions can make it a little tricky to find the correct runtime install when moving to run it on a server.
3. Lots of links on the web pointing to the old crystal decisions site. Now part of SAP, when I was looking for items, a lot of the links were broken/redirecting to SAP.
4. For me, this was a deal breaker - had to incorporate a lot of dynamic images - memory usage really shot up to the point where we had to swap it out.

Comment: can you please tell me some drawbacks about crystal reports? thnaks

Comment: please point out some major drawbacks for Crystal Reports for large amount data.